# How does ssh server defines which key to use first having more than 1?

Tags: ssh, configuration, sshd, public-key-authentication

I have just found out that on my Ubuntu machine I have more public keys to serve in `/etc/ssh` directory:

```
$ ll /etc/ssh
total 296K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 237K lip  3  2013 moduli
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.7K kwi 17 12:43 ssh_config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.7K mar 25 23:06 ssh_config.dpkg-old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.7K kwi 17 12:43 ssh_config.lwidentity.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.7K mar 25 23:06 ssh_config.lwidentity.orig
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.6K kwi 17 12:43 sshd_config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.6K kwi 17 12:43 sshd_config.lwidentity.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.5K mar 25 23:06 sshd_config.lwidentity.orig
-rw------- 1 root root  672 sty  4  2014 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  605 sty  4  2014 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw------- 1 root root  227 sty  4  2014 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  177 sty  4  2014 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw------- 1 root root 1.7K sty  4  2014 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  397 sty  4  2014 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  338 kwi 17 12:36 ssh_import_id
```

Having this and :

```
$ find /etc/ssh  ~/.ssh -name "*.pub" -exec ssh-keygen -l -f {} \;
256 da:f0:03:79:68:f8:04:b1:07:d8:8f:fe:3d:91:0e:aa  root@icanseeyou (ECDSA)
2048 3f:d7:9f:68:1b:b3:1a:a9:47:5b:47:5b:27:88:8c:aa  root@icanseeyou (RSA)
1024 7f:24:ca:0f:e3:84:8e:f9:1c:b3:49:d1:f4:39:a1:aa  root@icanseeyou (DSA)
4096 ae:86:c9:88:36:36:37:2f:84:5b:83:b4:45:17:41:aa  USER@icanseeyou (RSA)
```

I always get the ECDSA key as the first one (the one that is served)

```
$ ssh -p 222 USER@localhost
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:222 ([127.0.0.1]:222)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is da:f0:03:79:68:f8:04:b1:07:d8:8f:fe:3d:91:0e:aa.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
 11 HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
 12 HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
 13 HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

How does this work ? Why is the ECDSA key the first one to be served ?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't looked at the code, but:

ECDSA host keys are preferred when learning a host's keys for the first time,
   or can be learned using ssh-keyscan(1).

Source: http://openbsd.das.ufsc.br/openssh/txt/release-5.7